# Change fields name while fetching record in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I want to change field name and while fetching record from database
Ex.

```
$query = $formsElements->find('all')
            ->where(['Forms.slug' => 'allergy'])
            ->contain(['Forms'=>['fields'=>['id', 'name']], 'Elements']);
```

Above is my query and in same query i want to change name of "id" field as form_id.

Can you guys please suggest better ways to handle this without virtual field.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can use an alias, the [**manual**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data) says

> You can set aliases for fields by providing fields 
>   as an associative array:

So all you have to do is:

```
->contain([
    'Forms'=>[
        'fields'=>[
            'form_id' => 'id',
            'name'
        ]
    ], 
    'Elements'
]);
```